All my snap user data is lost
Single boot Ubuntu system, recently upgraded to 24.04, running on a Lenovo i3 Ideapd.
I had a system freeze  and had to use Alt-sysreq REISUB to restart.  When the system restarted I found that Firefox acted like a new install - everything gone - profiles, bookmarks, passwords, history, etc.
On further investigation I find ~/snap to be empty and newly created.  It seems likely that the entire ~/snap directory got corrupted in the recovery and snap has created a new folder.
I've not opened any other snaps yet (Thunderbird, whatsapp, chromium and a bunch of others, with a number of profiles) and am hoping that I can find a way of recovering some or all my snap application user data.
Any suggestions please?

Thanks, all.
@guiverc - no changes to mount points recently, but I'll explore the option of shadowed directories anyway and post back
@graham: sadly I did not have a firefox account - guess I will going forward!  The issue is bigger than this however, and the loss of my Thunderbird profile (and all email databases) is the bigun.
@user535733 - no hidden dir.  will check lost& found and post back
If / once I recover, this will be the end of snap distributions for me.  After 18 months of minor annoyances and crashes from snaps, this loss of everything is just not acceptable.

I wouldn't expect an issue after a SysRq-REISUB as you've attempted to sync buffers prior to reboot... so I'd check you didn't shadow directories due to a file-system table (/etc/fstab) or other change, which would cause your directories to be shadowed or not seen, thus the system is trying to help you by re-creating them on the new location that exists due to shadow... I don't know, but have you made changes recently, related to file-system or mount points?

I had a similar experience (not the same scenario tho) and what it turned oout to be was that I had been logged out of my Firefox account. Logged back in to it and order was restored. You did set up a Firefox account?

If ~/snap seems empty, then 1) Double check that you can see hidden files, and 2) Check for a lost+found directory in the root (/). After recovery, consider running a SMART test on your storage hardware, and a thorough fsck on the filesystem.
